"input token account not found" when trying to sell/swap tokens to SOL
Heyhey!
I'm currently writing a tool that lets me buy/sell/swap Tokens on the Solana blockchain.
Buying (swapping SOL for any Token) "seems" to work, I get the Tokens into my wallet and the transactions are going through SolScan.io Transaction.
Weirdly I cannot swap this tokens back to solana anywhere exept on the raydium-platform. Trying so (e.g. through my Phantom Wallet), I get an "InvalidSPLTokenProgram" Error.
Now I modified my Function to not only buy, but also sell Tokens to SOL.
But for some reason, I only get "input token account not found".
This is the Code which handles the Swap Transaction:
const createSwapTransaction = async ({ poolInfo, poolKeys, amountIn, slippage, isSelling = false, tokenAddress }) => {
  txSemaphore.release();
  await txSemaphore.acquire();
  try {
    console.log('\n=== Erstelle Swap Transaction ===');
    console.log(`Operation: ${isSelling ? 'Verkauf' : 'Kauf'}`);
    
    if (!poolInfo || !poolKeys) {
      throw new Error('Fehlende Pool-Informationen');
    }

    // Get mints as PublicKey instances
    const mintA = new PublicKey(poolKeys.mintA.address || poolKeys.mintA);
    const mintB = new PublicKey(poolKeys.mintB.address || poolKeys.mintB);
    const tokenPubKey = new PublicKey(tokenAddress);
    const WSOL = new PublicKey("So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112");
    const USDC = new PublicKey("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v");

    let inputMint, outputMint, fixedSide;
    if (isSelling) {
      // Selling logic - determine if token is base or quote
      if (mintA.equals(tokenPubKey)) {
        inputMint = mintA;
        outputMint = mintB;
        fixedSide = 'in';  // Token is base
      } else if (mintB.equals(tokenPubKey)) {
        inputMint = mintB;
        outputMint = mintA;
        fixedSide = 'out'; // Token is quote
      } else {
        throw new Error('Token nicht im Pool gefunden');
      }
    } else {
      // Buying logic
      if (mintA.equals(WSOL) || mintA.equals(USDC)) {
        inputMint = mintA;
        outputMint = mintB;
      } else {
        inputMint = mintB;
        outputMint = mintA;
      }
      fixedSide = 'in';
    }

    console.log(`Input Mint: ${inputMint.toString()}`);
    console.log(`Output Mint: ${outputMint.toString()}`);
    console.log(`Amount In: ${amountIn.toString()}`);
    console.log(`Fixed Side: ${fixedSide}`);

    const amountOutMin = calculateAmountOutMin(amountIn, slippage);
    console.log(`Amount Out Min: ${amountOutMin.toString()}`);

    // Get input token account
    const inputTokenAccounts = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(wallet.publicKey, {
      mint: inputMint,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    });

    if (inputTokenAccounts.value.length === 0 && isSelling) {
      throw new Error('Kein Input Token Account gefunden');
    }

    const inputTokenAccount = inputTokenAccounts.value[0]?.pubkey || 
                            await getAssociatedTokenAddress(inputMint, wallet.publicKey);

    // Handle WSOL account for output when selling
    const outputUseSolBalance = outputMint.equals(WSOL);
    let wsolAccount, wsolInstructions;
    
    if (outputUseSolBalance && isSelling) {
      const rent = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(165);
      const newAccount = Keypair.generate();
      
      wsolAccount = newAccount.publicKey;
      wsolInstructions = [
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
          fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
          newAccountPubkey: newAccount.publicKey,
          lamports: rent,
          space: 165,
          programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeAccountInstruction(
          newAccount.publicKey,
          WSOL,
          wallet.publicKey,
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      ];
    }

    const swapParams = {
      poolInfo,
      poolKeys,
      amountIn,
      amountOut: amountOutMin,
      fixedSide,
      version: poolInfo.version,
      userKeys: {
        tokenAccounts: [inputTokenAccount],
        owner: wallet.publicKey,
        payer: wallet.publicKey
      },
      config: {
        associatedOnly: false,
        checkCreateATAOwner: true,
        inputUseSolBalance: !isSelling && inputMint.equals(WSOL),
        outputUseSolBalance
      }
    };

    console.log('Rufe Raydium Swap API auf...');
    const swapData = await withRetry(
      async () => await raydium.liquidity.swap(swapParams),
      3,
      2000
    );

    if (!swapData?.transaction) {
      throw new Error('Ungültige Swap-Transaktionsdaten erhalten');
    }

    // Build transaction
    let transaction = new Transaction();
    
    // Add compute budget
    const computeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: 600000 });
    const priorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ microLamports: 1_700_000 });
    
    transaction.add(computeUnits)
              .add(priorityFee);

    // Add WSOL account creation if needed
    if (wsolInstructions) {
      transaction.add(...wsolInstructions);
    }

    // Add swap instructions
    transaction.add(...swapData.transaction.instructions);

    // Add WSOL cleanup if needed
    if (wsolAccount) {
      transaction.add(
        createCloseAccountInstruction(
          wsolAccount,
          wallet.publicKey,
          wallet.publicKey
        )
      );
    }

    const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');
    transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
    transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

    if (swapData.signers?.length) {
      transaction.partialSign(...swapData.signers);
    }

    return {
      transaction,
      computeUnitLimit: 600000,
      priorityMicroLamports: 1_700_000,
      amountOutMin,
      inputMint: inputMint.toString(),
      outputMint: outputMint.toString()
    };

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in createSwapTransaction:', error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    txSemaphore.release();
  }
};

Any Idea where I have messed up?
Here's my whole LOG Output when trying to sell a Token:
=== Starting Sell Process ===
Selling token: 7QMNpJByT8AhngnBwPMCtCVzPozVMDaNiXvytDp8NoUa
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 500ms delay...
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 1000ms delay...
Token Amount to Sell: 158900340

=== Pool Selection ===
Validiere SOL Pools: 1
Validiere USDC Pools: 0
Keine Pools zum Vergleichen

Beste gefundene Pools:
- Bester SOL Pool: 61YkBVTpcUF6cXgr7XxfEs4WNqZNu76SoEuJRWbRLYsA (TVL: $304049.8)
- Bester USDC Pool: Keiner (TVL: $0)
Wähle SOL Pool als besten Pool

Pool Info erhalten:
{
  "id": "61YkBVTpcUF6cXgr7XxfEs4WNqZNu76SoEuJRWbRLYsA",
  "version": 4,
  "status": 6,
  "programId": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
  "mintA": {
    "chainId": 101,
    "address": "7QMNpJByT8AhngnBwPMCtCVzPozVMDaNiXvytDp8NoUa",
    "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "logoURI": "",
    "symbol": "",
    "name": "",
    "decimals": 6,
    "tags": [],
    "extensions": {}
  },
  "mintB": {
    "chainId": 101,
    "address": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
    "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "logoURI": "",
    "symbol": "",
    "name": "",
    "decimals": 9,
    "tags": [],
    "extensions": {}
  },
  "rewardDefaultInfos": [],
  "rewardDefaultPoolInfos": "Ecosystem",
  "price": 0.000039836279632563994,
  "mintAmountA": 15932659.008352,
  "mintAmountB": 634.697859547,
  "baseReserve": "0e7d9c7b0360",
  "quoteReserve": "93c6f0c1db",
  "feeRate": 0.0025,
  "openTime": "1732712520",
  "tvl": 0,
  "day": {
    "volume": 0,
    "volumeQuote": 0,
    "volumeFee": 0,
    "apr": 0,
    "feeApr": 0,
    "priceMin": 0,
    "priceMax": 0,
    "rewardApr": []
  },
  "week": {
    "volume": 0,
    "volumeQuote": 0,
    "volumeFee": 0,
    "apr": 0,
    "feeApr": 0,
    "priceMin": 0,
    "priceMax": 0,
    "rewardApr": []
  },
  "month": {
    "volume": 0,
    "volumeQuote": 0,
    "volumeFee": 0,
    "apr": 0,
    "feeApr": 0,
    "priceMin": 0,
    "priceMax": 0,
    "rewardApr": []
  },
  "pooltype": [],
  "farmUpcomingCount": 0,
  "farmOngoingCount": 0,
  "farmFinishedCount": 0,
  "type": "Standard",
  "marketId": "YseMkZ1ADs18DgX9fufs78GMGryfxjps3HBYdM4Kvjf",
  "configId": "9DCxsMizn3H1hprZ7xWe6LDzeUeZBksYFpBWBtSf1PQX",
  "lpPrice": 0,
  "lpAmount": 0,
  "lpMint": {
    "chainId": 101,
    "address": "5Hsxga1LJMqGDCKHoapqCJuFfZYKzn3Moij9Y2tkNyc5",
    "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "logoURI": "",
    "symbol": "",
    "name": "",
    "decimals": 6,
    "tags": [],
    "extensions": {}
  },
  "burnPercent": 0
}

=== Berechne Verkaufsbetrag ===
Pool Preis: 0.000039836279632563994
Token Menge: 158900340
Erwarteter Output: 6329 lamports
Geschätzter Price Impact: 0.00%

Pool Details:
Token Reserve A: 15932659.008352
Token Reserve B: 634.697859547
Pool Fee Rate: 0.25%

=== Preis-Prüfung ===
Price Impact: 0.00% (Max: 20%)
Expected Output: 6329 lamports (Min: 1000)
Impact OK: true
Output OK: true
Erstelle Swap Transaction...

=== Erstelle Swap Transaction ===
Operation: Verkauf
Input Mint: 7QMNpJByT8AhngnBwPMCtCVzPozVMDaNiXvytDp8NoUa
Output Mint: So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112
Amount In: 158900340
Fixed Side: in
Amount In: 158900340
Amount Out Min: 143010306
Amount Out Min: 143010306
Rufe Raydium Swap API auf...
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 500ms delay...
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 1000ms delay...
Versuch 1 fehlgeschlagen. Warte 2000ms...
Versuch 2 fehlgeschlagen. Warte 4000ms...
Error in createSwapTransaction: Error: ["input token account not found",{"token":"So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112","inputTokenUseSolBalance":false,"associatedOnly":false}]
    at Fo.logAndCreateError (/mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2/lib/index.js:1:101124)
    at Fo.swap (/mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2/lib/index.js:1:291788)
    at async /mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/server.js:1286:19
    at async withRetry (/mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/server.js:232:14)
    at async createSwapTransaction (/mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/server.js:1285:22)
    at async sellToken (/mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/server.js:1637:24)
    at async /mnt/SolanaNodeJSBot/server.js:1776:5
Fehler während des Verkaufsprozesses: ["input token account not found",{"token":"So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112","inputTokenUseSolBalance":false,"associatedOnly":false}


I'm not sure if this is correct, but since the error comes from the Raydium API, and it's reporting "input token account not found", it probably means that inputTokenAccount hasn't been created. You'll need to create the account first with something like https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d1e018f731a6a90a3a6023113d911ca7bf566879/token/js/src/actions/createAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L21
